# How to configure a global JNDI datasource in Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource

I'm struggling to configure a simple JNDI pooled datasource in Tomcat 6.0.32.

I want to create the datasource definition outside my web application artifact. Basically I don't want my application to know the credentials to access the database server.
I was under the assumption that, like in Weblogic, it should be possible to create a "global" JNDI datasource in Tomcat, but so far I have been unsuccessful.

I have tried to add the datasource definition in CATALINA_HOME/conf/context:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
 auth="Container"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
 factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.1.1.1.:xxx"
 user="xxxx"
 password="yyyy"/>
```

The result is that the server outputs the following line, when booting:

```
SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=DataSource,path=/,host=localhost,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/mydb"
```

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Move your data source configuration to server.xml `<GlobalNamingResources>`. (And don't forget to add the driver jar file to tomcat lib). 
Configure your context.xml so that all Application are aware of the global resource.

```
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <ResourceLink global="jdbc/mydb" name="jdbc/mydb" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

Comment: If I move the Resource definition to the GlobalNamingResources section of server.xml, I get the same result: SEVERE: Null component Catalina:type=DataSource,path=/,host=localhost,class=javax.sql.DataSource,name="jdbc/selfcare"

Comment: Have you updated context.xml to link to the global resource? Have you put the oracle driver in the tomcat libraries? Have you restarted the server? Redeployed your application? Cleaned the cache?

Comment: Have you updated context.xml to link to the global resource? > YES
Have you put the oracle driver in the tomcat libraries? > YES, CATALINA_HOME/lib
Have you restarted the server? YES
Redeployed your application? > There is no application deployed
Cleaned the cache? > YES

Comment: I have also tried to set the log level to debug to figure out what is going on, but no luck. Same message.

Comment: Ok, your example was talking about jdbc/mydb, your error is talking about ­jdbc/selfcare? Are they both correctly configuring a Resource for Oracle Database Connection Pool? Have you given different names to your global resource and context.xml resource link name?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g) about configuring and using Oracle data sources.

Comment: And one more thing, are you using the correct server.xml and context.xml files? Sometimes tools such as Eclipse keeps separeted configuration files. If you are using some kind of intermediary tool, try starting the container from command line.

Comment: The mydb/selfcare was a typo. I have fixed it in the question. I'm editing the files on a freshly unzipped Tomcat. Several people reported the error I'm seeing but couldn't really find a solution.

Comment: Hum... Everything is running smooth here with a h2 database and a just downloaded Tomcat 6.0 distro. Can you lose the factory parameter in your resource configuration? Does it work when you declare the resouce in a application specific manner? (Take a look at the doc I mentioned two comments ago).

Comment: That made the trick!. I have tried removing the factory setting earlier, while trying the resource in the context.xml file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to be of service. Now let's start an up voting party (kidding)!

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake:  `user="xxxx"`, you need to write `username="xxxx"` instead.