# Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 causes context path to stop cooperating

Tags: xml, jsp, tomcat, contextpath

I have a webapp that is working swimmingly in Tomcat 6. Let's say it's running on `server:8282/MyApplication`. I have a context xml that looks like this:

```
<Context crossContext="true"
         debug="5"
         docBase="MyApplication"
         path="MyApplication"
         reloadable="true">
```

In my application, my links look like

```
server:8282/MyApplication/myAction.do?params=blah
```

When I switch it to Tomcat 7, it seems to change the link to:

```
server8282/myAction.do?params=blah
```

I haven't changed -anything- in the application, it's the same code in both places. Is there some global setting I can change to get that "MyApplication" back in?

Edit: the code that generates the link is, as an example,:

```
<a href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/myAction.do?params=blah">do the blah</a>
```

Comment: Show us the code that generates that link.

Comment: Added the jsp that creates the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like something is wrong with your deploying process, and for some reason Tomcat is trying to serve your application at the root of the server, because of that your `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` is returning empty.

Since I'm not sure of your exactly deployment requirements, try one of the following procedures. Just to be sure and avoid configuration conflicts, do it on a brand new Tomcat 7 installation:

1. If you have a `MyApplication.war` file just drop it at `<CATALINA_HOME>\webapps`, do not use any context files (be ware of context files inside the war file, i.e., `/META-INF/context.xml`)
2. If you have an exploded application, create a folder `MyApplication` inside `webapps` and drop the application contents there (again, no `context.xml`).

If you really need to keep your application outside of `webapps`:

1. Add a new `Context` element to `<CATALINA_HOME>\conf\server.xml` inside `<Host>`:

   ```
   <Context path="/MyApplication"
            docBase="/absolute/physical/path/to/MyApplication" 
            reloadable="true"
            crossContext="true">
   ```
2. Alternatively create a `MyApplication.xml` file in `<CATALINA_HOME>\Catalina\localhost` with the content mentioned above.

For further info refer to [The Context Container documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).

Comment: Hi Anthony - I have a resource (a tomcat managed SQL connection) in the context.xml, which is why the file exists in the first place. Is there a better place for that so I can get rid of the context.xml?

Comment: Since Tomcat has no support for [@DataSourceDefinition](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/sql/DataSourceDefinition.html), `Context` is still the way to go. But you can live without a application specific `context.xml` by moving your `<Resource>` tag to `<CATALINA_HOME>\conf\server.xml` `<GlobalNamingResources>` and declaring a `<ResourceLink>`  at `<CATALINA_HOME>\conf\context.xml`. This will create a global datasource (accessible by all applications). Take a look at one of my previous answers for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997122

Comment: This is excellent. I've added a temporary measure of using a silly `AppConstants.CONTEXT_PATH` with a `public static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/MyApplication";` as a stop-gap measure. I'd prefer something more robust, as this is an issue in a number of apps. Thanks!