# Incorrect context returned from request.getContextPath()

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee

I have a java servlet that I am running under the root context of tomcat, with the following context definition.

```
<Context docBase="/local/content/tomcat/webapps/app.war" debug="0"     reloadable="false" path="" sessionCookiePath="/">
```

My url for loading the page is localhost/ without any addition path data. When I call getContextPath on the request I get back "app" whereas I would expect "".

I have found various questions about the opposite, getting "" when expecting something else, but not getting something else when expecting ""

(example)
[Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 7 causes context path to stop cooperating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905388/tomcat-6-to-tomcat-7-causes-context-path-to-stop-cooperating)

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You would want to replace the ROOT web application in Tomcat

Comment: Why don't you set path to `"/"`?

Comment: Your `docBase` is invalid. It needs to be a directory, not a WAR file.

Comment: I tried setting the path to "/" and request.getContextPath still returned "app". Additionaly, I did try changing the docBase, it did not work. @mechkov, not sure what you mean. The app is hosted at the root path when you hit the URL.

Comment: I suspect double-deployment. The `docBase` can certainly be a WAR file and the correct `path` for the ROOT application is `""`, not `"/"`.